# How to buy ETH by "in app purchase" in iOS?

Tags: ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, polygon, web3-providers, ios

In my iOS nft (wallet & minting) project, when a user creates a new wallet, initially it has 0 ETH. So I want to buy some ETH/Matic for minting or other stuffs.

**Need to know, how can I buy some ETH directly in exchange of $$ using "in-app purchase" in swift implementation.**
Currently I'm using boilertalk's web3swift for for web3 facilities. Quick help will be appreciated highly, Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Apple reviewers will reject that feature, unless you register as an exchange or have financial institution license. See the [App Store Guideline 3.1.5.](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

> (iii) Exchanges: Apps may facilitate transactions or transmissions of
> cryptocurrency on an approved exchange, provided they are offered only
> in countries or regions where the app has appropriate licensing and
> permissions to provide a cryptocurrency exchange.